# Using JavaScript / jQuery to Search Keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have a static site and I was wondering if it is possible to have a search form on the website and then use JavaScript of jQuery to search the page for certain keywords and then use jQuery to add a class or something.

Comment: Every browser supports `Ctrl+F` out of the box.

Comment: But being able search would also be great.

Comment: http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/12/20/jquery-search-and-highlight/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the JQuery "Contains" Selector

- http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/
- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_contains.asp

Then use the addClass() method to assign your class

- http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div>John Resig</div>

  <div>George Martin</div>
  <div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
  <div>J. Ohn</div>


  <script>
  $("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
      </script>

  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: `jQuery.contains` doesn't do text matching, it looks for elements inside other elements (e.g. `<A>` inside `<DIV>`.

Comment: Never mind, I was thinking of the `contains()` function, not the `:contains` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible:

```
var text = $('body').html();
var split = text.split(/whatever/);
$('body').html(split[0] + '<span class="match">' + 'whatever' + '</span> + split[1]);
```

Comment: That will break things if the search string matches something in the HTML rather than the rendered text.

Comment: -1 this will also replace element attributes and might break the page.